# Derivative of $x\times n - 2^{\log_2 {x \times n}}$

Tags: limits, derivatives, logarithms, exponentiation

I have a problem with solving derivative of $f(x)$ in this case:
$$f(x) = x\times 10^9 - 2^{\log_{10} x\times 10^9}$$
This is what I have:
$$f^\prime(x) = \lim_{m\to0} {f(x+m) - f(x)\over m}$$
$$= \lim_{m\to0} {{((x+m)\times 10^9 - 2^{\log_{10} (x+m)\times 10^9}) - (x\times 10^9 - 2^{\log_{10} x\times 10^9})} \over m}$$
$$= \lim_{m\to0} {{m\times10^9 - 2^{\log_{10} (x+m)\times 10^9} + 2^{\log_{10} x\times10^9}} \over m}$$
From here I can't move. I can probably calculate ${m \over m}$ to have problem in this state
$$= \lim_{m\to0} 10^9 + {{- 2^{\log_{10} (x+m)\times 10^9} + 2^{\log_{10} x\times10^9}} \over m}$$
But if $m$ becomes $0$, it looks like the result is...

$$f^\prime(x) = 10^9+0$$
...because ${x \over 0}=0$.

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this?

Please help.

Comment: Um... did you notice that $2^{\log_2(x \times 10^9)} = x \times 10^9$, so that your function $f$ is just $0$?

Comment: Sorry, edited. I'm not very familiar with formatting here.

Comment: Ahhh, okay. Fine. :) Now it seems like a more legitimate question! Do you know about the chain rule?

Comment: No. Absolutely nothing. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to see that is a mistake to think that $\frac{x}{0}=0$, you can not say that. If you have a limit process like : $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}1/x=\infty$. But let's go to the correct answer :

First note  that $f(x)= x\times 10^9 - 2^{\log_{10}x\times 10^9}$ can be separated in two functions, first $h(x)= x\times 10^9$ and $g(x)=2^{\log_{10}x\times 10^9}$, so 
$f(x)=h(x)-g(x)$ it's  clear also that $f'(x)=h'(x)-g'(x)$ and $h'(x)=10^9$ so let's calculate $g'(x)$, we first use a simple property of logarithm that change the product into sum, so
$$g(x)=2^{\log_{10}x\times 10^9}= 2^{\log_{10}10^9+\log_{10}x=2^9\times 2^{log_{10}x}}$$
so our work is to derivate $r(x)=2^{log_{10}x}$ now you need to know that
$$(a^x)'=a^x\ln a \;\;\;\mbox{and}\;\;\; (\log_{b} x)'= \frac{1}{x\ln b}$$
and now you apply the chain rule as follows:

$$r'(x) = (2^{\log_{10}x})'= 2^{\log_{10}x}\ln 10 \frac{1}{x \ln 10}=\frac{2^{\log_{10}x}}{x}$$

hence, $g'(x)=2^9\times r'(x)=\frac{2^{\log_{10}x\times 10^9}} {x}$
so $f'(x)=h'(x)-g'(x)=10^9-\frac{2^{\log_{10}x\times 10^9}} {x}$